# How to include $wpdb in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I've been developing for some time on a `plugin` in `wordpress`, but one problem keeps bugging me. I want to export a database-table as an excel file and therefor i need access to the global `$wpdb->variable` from a file in my plugin directory.

I found a blog entry that explains what classes i should include, but this doesn't work (link is below). As you can see, i do a `var_dump`, but it never reaches that point. If i leave the includes of `wp-config` and `wp-load` out of the code, the dump `returns NULL`, so i'm guessing there is a problem with the imports.

Anyway, i was hoping someone could help me with this problem. I don't necessarily need a fix for my approach, I just need a way to export an array of data (fetched from my db) to excel in wordpress. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/web-mysql/web-scripts/standalone-access-the-wordpress-database-using-wpdb/

```
include_once('../../../wp-config.php');
include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
include_once('../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');

var_dump($wpdb);
$filter = get_where_clause();
$order = get_order_by_clause();

$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_prefix . "team_data" . $filter . $order, ARRAY_A);

$result = array();
```

---

**EDIT:**
I cannot include the `wp-config`, it gives constant errors. I know where the bug is taking place, I just need to find a work-around. when looking at the `wp-settings` page (which is included by the wp-config) you will find this line of code:

```
foreach ( wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins() as $plugin )
    include_once( $plugin );
unset( $plugin );
```

this is where there is a bug. I just don't know how i should work around this bug.

**EDIT 2:**
Problem solved. When including the file, i included the `wp-config` more than once (even though i stated it should only be included one time). I solved the problem by using the following code.

```
global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

if(!isset($wpdb))
{
    require_once('../../../../wp-config.php');
    require_once('../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}
```

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? I only have this line: `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

Comment: 'require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');' is in the wp-config file. you should look for the bugged lines in wp-settings.php :) (and i am using the latest version of wordpress btw).

Comment: What exact error messages are you getting?

Comment: none, the page just stops rendering and is returned blank. I found the bug was there just by doing some var_dump() and seeing until what point it kept showing up on the screen. And after that line, the page stopped rendering.

Comment: I updated my Post. Check if you can get some Error-Output when you turn the debugging features on.

Comment: turning the debug on, i found that i was having trouble with another plugin i wrote. there was a duplicate functionname that was throwing a fatal error when i wanted to include the wp-config. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Always happy to help :D Have a nice one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're creating a WordPress plugin, you don't need to include those files manually.

If you want to export your table, why don't you create a function/class for it and pass the `$wpdb` to it (if you need it). You can also use the normal [MySQLi](http://de3.php.net/mysqli)-class (from PHP) do access your MySQL Database.

---

If you simply want to access the MySQL Database with the stored login-values which are used by WordPress, you can include the `wp_config`-file from the WordPress root-directory. It has some (self explaining) global fields which you could use to connect to your database:

```
include "WP-ROOT-PATH/wp-config.php";
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Test the connection:
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    // Connection Error
    exit("Couldn't connect to the database: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

After that you have a instance of the MySQLi-class (as mentioned above) which you can use to access your Database.

I'm however not sure if this is the perfect way to go but it sure works.

---

To Debug WordPress (if something doesn't work and there is no Error-Message) you should activate debugging in the `wp-config.php`-file:

```
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Also, if you're testing your PHP-Scripts on a local server, you should turn the `display_error` to `on` in your `php.ini`-file:

```
; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments.
display_errors = On
```

However this should only be done on your local test-server, not in a productive scenario.

Comment: I do have to include them manually, because if i want to trigger an excel download, i cannot do that from within the admin.php of wordpress (the header information cannot be passed, don't ask me why). So i call a php-file from my plugin-directory, but this cannot access the $wpdb variable or any other variable i would need to access the wordpress db for that matter.

Comment: The header information can't be send because you change the header after something was already printed. You should (like i said) create a new class in a new file and pass it the `$wpdb`-Object.

Comment: And how should i pass the $wpdb-variable to that class? because the way i am calling the file now is by redirecting to another php-page. (html shown below).


<a href="../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/to_excel.php?filter=<?php echo($filter_name) ?>" class="button-primary">Save as excel</a>

Comment: Sorry, that was a misunderstanding on my side. I updated my post, take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have gotten a little closer to solving the problem. I have updated my original post with some more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

get away from hard solutions! and just use :

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
```