# WordPress $wpdb returns null

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin to transfer data from FTP sever to local server and update the wp database **using a cron job**.

The plugin structure is as follow:

*plugin folder

- plugin mainfile.php (to register the plugin)
- Data Folder
- class lib folder (which has 3 php classes, class1.php, class2.php, and class3.php)

Now, inside mainfile.php I have a reference to $wpdb using global $wpdb and it works as expected (to create database tables).

The problem is when I try to get a reference to the $wpdb using global inside any of the classes in the lib folder it returns NULL.

could you please help :(

Here is the code the in the main plugin file.php

```
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    function FTP_activate(){

    global $wpdb;

    $market_data_table = $wpdb->prefix . "marketData";

    $market_data_table;

    if($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE ' . $market_data_table) != 
    $market_data_table)
    {
        $sql =  'CREATE TABLE ' . $market_data_table . ' (
                              `PID` int(20) NOT NULL,
                              `field2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                              `field3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
                              `field4` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                              `field5` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
                              `field6` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
                              `
                              PRIMARY KEY (PID)
                            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';
    }


    dbDelta($sql);




    $image_table = $wpdb->prefix . "marketPhotos";

    if($wpdb->get_var('SHOW TABLES LIKE ' . $image_table) != 
$image_table)
    {
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE ' .  $image_table . ' (
                              `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
                              `PID` int(20) NOT NULL,
                              `PhotoNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                              `Description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                              `FileName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
                              PRIMARY KEY (ID)
                            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';
    }

    dbDelta($sql);

}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'FTP_activate');}
```

And here part of the code in class1.php that I am having problem with which is inside lib folder

```
    class FTPTransfer{
    const FTP_CONNECTION_ERROR = 0;
    const FTP_CONNECTION_SUCSS = 1;
    const FTP_LOGIN_ERROR      = 0;
    const FTP_LOGIN_SUCSS      = 1;

    private $base_data_directory;
    private $new_imgs = array();

    private $ftp_server = "servername";
    private $ftp_username = "username";
    private $ftp_password = "password";

    private $logger;


    public function __construct($base_path){

    global $wpdb;

    $this->base_data_directory = $base_path . "/FTPData";


    }   

    public function ftp_transfer(){


    var_dump($wpdb);

    if(!$ftp = $this->ftpCheckConnection()){
        exit();
    }


    $dir = ftp_pwd($ftp);
    $file_date = date('ymd');
    $img_folder_date = date('Ymd');
    $file_pattern = 'MktData'. $file_date . '_*.csv';
    $img_folder_pattern = 'MktPhotos' . $img_folder_date . '*';


    $temp_file = 'temp.csv';

    $img_folder = ftp_nlist($ftp, $dir.$img_folder_pattern);
    $file = ftp_nlist($ftp, $dir.$file_pattern)[0];
```

Comment: Share your code, please

Comment: Will please elaborate your question in the form of code?

Answer (score 0):

$wpdb cannot be reached because there hasn't been any reference made to it in that file. You either need to include that file in another file that has an instance of $wpdb already called such as your mainfile.php. Or include $wpdb directly into that file by doing something like what can be found here... [How to include $wpdb in wordpress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217098/how-to-include-wpdb-in-wordpress-plugin)

My hunch though is that you are not calling any of the library files so they are not working at all.