# Call to a member function insert() on null

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have an insert problem in WordPress, I have this error message when processing the form. 
I upload an image and then insert the url of the image into the bdd.
The upload of the image is working but at the moment of making the insert I have a mistake:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null

My script treatment_upload:

```
lalala();

function lalala() {
    $extensions_valides = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

    $extension_upload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['icone']['name'], '.'), 1));
    if (in_array($extension_upload, $extensions_valides))
        echo "Extension correcte";
///Créer un identifiant difficile à deviner
    $nom = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


    $nom = "fichier/$nom.{$extension_upload}";
    $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icone']['tmp_name'], $nom);
    if ($resultat)
        echo "Transfert réussi";

    $url_img = "wp-content/plugin/fichier/$nom";

    blabla($url_img);
//pause($url_img);
}



function blabla($url_img){
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
        'test', //table name
        array(
    'id' => "",
    'titre' => $url_img,
        ), //columns
        array(
    '%d',
    '%s',
        )
);
}
```

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/traitement_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <label for="icone">Upload image :</label><br />
     <input type="file" name="icone" id="icone" /><br />
<!--     <label for="mon_fichier">Fichier (tous formats | max. 1 Mo) :</label><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
     <input type="file" name="mon_fichier" id="mon_fichier" /><br />-->
     <label for="titre">Titre du fichier (max. 50 caractères) :</label><br />
     <input type="text" name="titre" value="Titre du fichier" id="titre" /><br />
     <label for="description">Description de votre fichier (max. 255 caractères) :</label><br />
     <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea><br />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should show the `$wpdb` definition.

Comment: Has WordPress actually made a connection to your database. It looks like maybe not

Comment: @ben, I think you should remove `id` from insert function and `$wpdb` define above all functions as global.

Answer (score 0):

The direct problem causing the message is that `$wpdb` variable is null. This suggests that your code is not running as a WordPress plugin, so the correct WordPress include files have not been included prior to the execution of your code. Solutions to this have been discussed in [How to include $wpdb in wordpress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217098/how-to-include-wpdb-in-wordpress-plugin)